# How to stack 2 div tags on top of each other inside another div tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a calendar and I am trying to add events to it. Each event has a style and will have a link associated with it. It seems to be doing OK when there is only one event per day, but the issue comes when I am trying to add 2 events inside a single day. I have played around with absolute and relative position but it doesn't seem to be working. I would like it to look like this:
[example Image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3860226/dwddwdwdwd.JPG)
but it actuallty looks like this: [actual html](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3860226/wsdfwerdxweqda.JPG)

Here is my Code:

CSS

```
.calendarDay {
position: relative;
clear: none;
width: 14.2851%;
height: 142px;
background-image: url(images/calendarDayBG.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
font-family: "Stag Sans book", "Arial";
font-size: 45pt;
vertical-align: top;
color: #4d4f53;
overflow: hidden;
top: 40px;
text-align: left;
}

.calendarDay h1 {
font-family: "Stag Sans light", "Arial";
font-size: 45pt;
text-overflow:clip;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

/* event styles */

```
    surgicalCare {
display: inline;
alignment-baseline:baseline;
background-color: #d75f17;
position: absolute;
}
surgicalCareStacked {
display: inline;
background-color: #d75f17;
position: absolute;
}
strategicaccounts {
display: block;
alignment-baseline:baseline;
background-color: #5e249e;
}
```

HTML

```
 <li class="fluid calendarDay zeroMargin_desktop">17<a href="EAST/msn.html"><div      class="fluid surgicalCareStacked">
     <p>E.A.S.T.</p>
   </div></a>
   <a href="EAST/sponsorship_EAST.html"><div class="fluid surgicalCare">
     <p>E.A.S.T.</p>
   </div></a></li>
```

I was thinking that I may need to use different styles: one for multiple events in a day "stacked," and one with a single event...but I could be totally wrong!

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you create a couple images that show what you want versus what you actually get?

Comment: What I am going for: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3860226/dwddwdwdwd.JPG but it looks like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3860226/wsdfwerdxweqda.JPG

Comment: Jonathan, can you elaborate? Do i still need the position style then? I played with the float: left; but i believe I may have had the display: inline; and/or position: absolute; will that override the float? Sorry I am new to html/css!

Comment: Could anyone please assist me? I never really got the problem resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Your images are not available for some reason. If I understand your question correctly, this is what you are looking for:

```
 ______________________
|     Parent div       |
|  __________________  |
| |   Child div 1    | |
| |                  | |
| |__________________| |
|  __________________  |
| |   Child div 2    | |
| |                  | |
| |__________________| |
|______________________|
```

Something like this would work:

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
        <!-- Stuff here -->
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
        <!-- Stuff here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
    width: 250px; // Or whatever width you need
}
```

This works because divs are block elements by default, so they span the whole width of their parent element, and force other elements down.